# XPath "how many elements in node?" with Microsoft EXCEL

Tags: xml, excel, xpath

I'm trying to use Microsoft Excel's FILTERXML function to grab data from an XML form.

I'm not quite sure why I'm unable to get a number response when I use certain XPath arguments.

Here's my XML:

```
<result>
<status>1</status>
<num_results>1</num_results>
<total_results>500</total_results>
<results_remaining>499</results_remaining>
<matches>
    <match>
        <radiant_team_id>0</radiant_team_id>
        <dire_team_id>0</dire_team_id>
        <players>
            <player>
                <account_id>141684701</account_id>
                <player_slot>0</player_slot>
                <hero_id>0</hero_id>
            </player>
            <player>
                <account_id>4294967295</account_id>
                <player_slot>1</player_slot>
                <hero_id>0</hero_id>
            </player>
            <player>
                <account_id>4294967295</account_id>
                <player_slot>2</player_slot>
                <hero_id>0</hero_id>
            </player>
        </players>
      </match>
   </matches>
</result>
```

I'm trying to use this XPath argument to count how many players pop up in a dynamic API that refreshes an XML form every so ofter. The player count varies from 0-10.

```
/result/matches/match/players[count(player)]
```

I get a #!VALUE error. Here's the MS Excel function argument I use:

```
=FILTERXML($A$2,"/result/matches/match/players/player[count(player)]")
```

Both arguments fail. Is there a way I can report how many player elements exist in the XML form by reporting to another cell in MS Excel?

Comment: The correct XPath for what you're trying to do is `count(/result/matches/match/players/player)`, but is looks like FILTERXML might only allow XPaths that evaluate to a node-set (and `count()` evaluates to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regular expressions instead?

```
<player>((?:.|\n)*?)</player>
```

Will get you all player tags and no wrestling with XPath. 
Inside this tag you can get the remaining ones e.g.

```
<account_id>((?:.|\n)*?)</account_id>
```

You can either use the VBA **CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")** objects:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx

Or I also created an addin with an embeded Excel UDF function  - **"GetRegex"** (a function u can use just as the FilterXML in Excel). See here:
http://blog.tkacprow.pl/excel-tools/excel-scrape-html-add/

An example to get the first player tag:

```
=GetRegex(A1;"<player>((?:.|\n)*?)</player>";0)
```

An example to get the second player tag:

```
=GetRegex(A1;"<player>((?:.|\n)*?)</player>";1)
```

You can nest them also:

```
=GetRegex(GetRegex(A1;"<player>((?:.|\n)*?)</player>");"<account_id>((?:.|\n)*?)</account_id>")
```

e.g. to get the first account_id.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't know VBA so I don't know how to do any regular expressions. I was trying to do everything in-house in Excel, but it seems like it's not really possible because it's not advanced to my tastes.

I tried downloading your plugin for Excel, but it gives me an error on your site, "/share/MD0_DATA/Web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/download-manager/cache/ must have to be writable!"

Comment: Ok. Actually regular expressions are not just VBA. They are used in all programming languages and even in excel find ctrl+f dialog. My addin however requires only knowing regex and not vba. Thx for the heads up however i will fix the download issue in an hour or so.

Comment: Ok fixed the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey tkacprow, I've been trying to use your addon for a bit. About "indexing", is there a way to incrementally increase the index number so I can extract the appropriate amount of matches from RegEx?

Comment: Sorry couldn't edit my comment further.

ex:
    =GetElementByRegex("URL_i_have","<img alt=""([^""""]*)",1)
I need it to range from 0-122